# IO::Socket::INET->new does not create a listening soket

Tags: perl, sockets

i am using IO::Socket::INET->new to create a listening socket
strangely, it is able to create a listensing socket if port number is 5 digit 
it i specify 4 digit number , it says it created succesfulty but netstat does not list

what could be issue

Answer (score 3):

You can't create sockets with port numbers lower than 1024 as an unprivileged user. Try running your program as root, or (probably better) use a higher port number.

Comment: hi i am trying to bind to port 2050 as root itself.  also i tried with many different ports 7000, 9000, etc. it wont work.  IO::Socket::INET->new  return a socket but netstat does not list that listen socket. if i use higher port number like 12000 etc then it works proper and netstat lists that.  its strange, i am not able to figure out why

Comment: - its resolved. i was not using proper netstat to see: now i use 'netstat -anp'